# What is origin of the term “dry” to mean lack of a sweet taste?

Tags: etymology, terminology, origin-unknown

I am aware that “London Dry” is a style of unsweetened gin and that this has influenced how we talk about other drinks. I am interested in why the word *dry* was initially used in this context to describe the taste.

The [dictionary definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dry?q=Dry) I have found is:

> If wine or other alcoholic drinks are dry, they do not taste sweet:
>
> dry cider/martini/sherry/wine
>
> On the whole, I like dry wine better than sweet.

**EDIT**: I now know that the origin most likely comes from wine, not gin.

Answer (score 6):

A search of the Early English Books Online database of books from 1450 to 1700 yields one instance of the phrase "dry wine" from a book published before 1700. From [*In Vino Veritas: or, A Conference Betwixt Chip the Cooper, and Dash the Drawer (Being Both Boozy) Discovering Some Secrets in the Wine-Brewing Trade*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Aa5kAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA31&dq=%22rough+wine%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwimkKjxtY31AhWKVs0KHcndBQY4ChDoAXoECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=%22rough%20wine%22&f=false) (1698)—one year earlier than the oldest instance cited by the OED (as reported in Greybeard's answer):

> *Dash*. The Palats of our Customers have more different gusts than the Moon has Figures; one must (as he calls it) have a ***dry Wine***, another a *rough Wine*; t'other a *smooth mellow Wine*, but most agree in a very strong Wine; which we know how to strengthen, with Brandy, or Spirits, which are cheaper, and to lengthen it; for the Fame of one extraordinary high priz'd Pipe of Canary (we buy) sells us twenty, and yet we perswade, 'tis all of that very Pipe; and so of Pontac (when in vogue) and of other Wines, (now) as *Barcelona*, *Gallicia*, *Lisbon*, *&c*.

As for the rationale for using *dry* in this way, Nathan Bailey, [*An Universal Etymological English Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=-FSYwRg7PU4C&pg=PP347&dq=%22FILETS+(in+Cookery)+Meat,+Fowl%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjTzPujuofrAhWxCTQIHfusBTwQ6AEwBXoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=dry%20dephlegmated&f=false), third edition (1726) offers this brief rationale in an entry devoted to *dry* in the wine sense:

> **DRY** (spoken of *Wine*) a Wine that by reason of Age, is pretty well dephlegmated, or has lost much of its waterish Quality.

Elsewhere in this dictionary, Bailey identifies *dephlegmated* as a "Chymical Term" meaning "cleared from Phlegm or Water" and *dephlegmation* as "a Separation of Phlegm or superfluous Water." The [second edition of Bailey's dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=UeUIAAAAQAAJ&pg=PT259&dq=%22flitch+of+bacon%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tqnmVPvQIZCOoQTYloG4Dw&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22dry%20exchange%22&f=false) (1724), however, lacks the wine-related entry for *dry*.

It would seem from Bailey's discussion that people in the early 1700s applied the term *dry* to wine that, because it was older, contained less "superfluous" water. Interestingly, neither Bailey in 1726 nor the author of *In Vino Veritas* in 1698 makes any explicit connection between *dry* and the meaning "free from sweetness or fruity flavor" ascribed to it by [Etymology Online](https://www.etymonline.com/word/dry) (and noted in user 66974's answer) as dating to 1700.

---

**Update (December 30, 2021): *A further look into early uses of 'dry' and its possible seventeenth-century antecedents***

Another wine term that appears in Bailey's third edition is *racy*:

> **RACY** {spoken of wine} that has by age lost its luscious quality.

But the [fourteenth edition of Bailey's *Universal Etymological Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=hwNAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PP693&dq=%22dry+wine%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjdntTwvI31AhXPVs0KHfEuCPs4FBDoAXoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22dry%20wine%22&f=false) (1751), although it retains the same definition of *dry* (in the wine sense) as the third edition, has a very different definition of *racy*:

> **RACY** {spoken of Wine} a Wine that still retains its rich Flavour ; this Word is used in Distinction to what is called a *dry Wine*.

So Bailey in 1751 seems to be contrasting *dry* with *flavorful*, not with *sweet*.

Thomas Dyche & William Pardon, [*A New General English Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=l0JgAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP236&dq=%22DRY+(A.)+That+has+none%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjOitS1soz1AhXfHjQIHS-ICX4Q6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=%22DRY%20(A.)%20That%20has%20none%22&f=false) (1735) offers this entry for *dry* as an adjective:

> **DRY** (A.) That has none, or very little Moisture ;  also a Cant Word for one that acts slily or cunningly, that is very reserved, and watches all Opportunities to say or do something for his own Advantage ; also when Wine by reason of Age is much dephlegmated, and its watry Taste considerably abated, or quite destroyed, it is said to be dry.

Although the focus of the relevant definition here is on dephlegmation (as in the third edition of Bailey's dictionary), the entry does connect dryness to an abatement in the wine's taste—albeit its "watry Taste"—not to an abatement in sweetness.

Ephraim Chambers, [*Cyclopaedia: Or, An Universal Dictionary of Arts and Sciences*](https://books.google.com/books?id=DHOj9vGhuroC&pg=RA52-PT38&dq=Wine+%22vegetable+bodies+and+fermented%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiCu_b8w4z1AhU1GTQIHcbwCq44ChDoAXoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=Wine%20%22vegetable%20bodies%20and%20fermented%22&f=false), second edition (1738), mentions dryness as a quality of wine twice in a lengthy discussion of the topic:

> **WINE**, *Vinum*, a brisk, agreeable, spirituous, and cordial liquor, drawn from vegetable bodies, and fermented. See VEGETABLE, and FERMENTATION.
>
> ...
>
> The goodness of *wine* consists in its being neat, dry, fine, bright, and brisk, without any taste of the soil, of a clean, steddy colour ; having a strength, without being heady ; a body, without being sour ;  and keeping, without growing hard, or eager.
>
> ...
>
> Wines, again, are distinguished, with regard to their quality, into *sweet wines*, *rough* or ***dry wines***, and *rich* or *luscious wines*, *vins de liquor* ; of which last, some are exceedingly sweet, others sweet and poignant ; all chiefly used by way of dram after meals, *&c*.

Significantly, Chambers lists "sweet wine" and "rough or dry wine" as two of the primary categories of wine when distinguished as to "quality." However, this split does not necessarily correspond to a simple division between "sugary"and "non-sugary." Complicating the sense of the terminology is this further comment in the same entry:

> Wine, in France, is distinguished, from the several degrees and steps of its preparation, into,
>
> ...
>
> *Sweet* WINE, *vin doux*, is that which has not yet worked, or fermented.

So, to the extent that French nomenclature crossed into English usage, "sweet wine" might refer to wine not yet fermented—that is, very young wine indeed. This sense of the term is obviously distinct from the notion of "sweet wine" as wine that has a sugary taste, although the latter meaning is evidently intended by Chambers in the discussion of "rich or luscious wines" and may well be the primary sense of "sweet wines" as he uses that term.

Instances of "sweet wine" in the more intuitive sense of "wine that tastes sweet" goes back much farther than instances of "dry wine" in any sense. For example, from Thomas Coane, [*The Haven of Health*](https://books.google.com/books?id=tY1mAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT16&dq=%22sweet+wine%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi4kav_yoz1AhWIQs0KHRzxBiUQ6AF6BAgKEAI#v=onepage&q=%22sweet%20wine%22&f=false) (1612):

> And if any be disposed to drinke Wine, they may learne to choose good Wine by fiue properties : First by the colour, as white, red, claret. Secondly by the taste, as sweet, soure, rough, light. Thirdly by the sauour or smell, as fragrant or otherwise. Fourthly, by the  substance, as thick, thinne, cleare or muddy. Fiftly by the age, as new or old.

The absence of *dry* from this list of taste characteristics strongly suggests that it was a relatively late addition to the English wine lexicon—certainly later than *rough* (which appears in Coane's 1610 discussion and is paired with *dry* in Chambers's 1738 coverage, although set in opposition to it in *In Vino Veritas*'s 1698 description).

Older still is a 1600 translation of Charles Stevens & John Liebault, [*Maison Rustique, or The Covnntrie Farme*](https://books.google.com/books?id=lh8DytLfi6QC&pg=PA741&dq=%22rough+wine%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjYxtiUpo31AhXOKM0KHU1XB5AQ6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=%22rough%20wine%22&f=false) (1600), which uses the terms rough and sharpe in connection with wine:

> The naturall and reclaimed plant of the blacke vine groweth euerie where : the wilde doth yeeld a sharpe and rough wine : such as that which groweth of ground newly broken vp : but the vine that is intended to be for claret wine, is planted halfe of black and halfe of a white vine, and thereupon standeth in neede of another manner of dressing and seate, then the common vine doth : in like sort it is harder to order well, as requiring a very great care to be taken about it, because the wine which commeth thereof, is most pleasant to the eie and of excellent taste, albeit it that it doe not nourish so much.

Other possible predecessor terms—besides *rough* and *sharp*—for *dry* as a descriptive term for wine are *austere* and *harsh*. Thus, John Gerard, [*The Herball or Generall Historie of Plantes*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ml9fAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA875&dq=%22harsh+wine%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjEz-XMnI31AhW5CTQIHRadBfYQ6AF6BAgKEAI#v=onepage&q=%22harsh%20wine%22&f=false), second edition (1636) offers this note in his discussion of "the manured vine":

> There be others [that is, other grape vines] which make a black and obscure red wine, whereof some bring bigger clusters, and consist of greater grapes, others of lesser ; some grow more clustered or closer together, others looser ; some haue but one stone, others more ; some make a more austere or harsh wine, others a more sweet ;: of some the old wine is best, of diuers the first yeres wine is most excellent ; some bring forth fruit foure square, of which kindes we haue great plenty.

A 1686 translation of Castor DaGualdo, [*A Treasure of Health*](https://books.google.com/books?id=tBZmAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA230&dq=%22rough+wine%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjYxtiUpo31AhXOKM0KHU1XB5AQ6AF6BAgGEAI#v=onepage&q=%22rough%20wine%22&f=false) (1686) uses *dry* several times in connection with wine characteristics:

> *Of Old Wine*
>
> When the Wine is above four years old, it is hot and **dry** in the third degree, and the older it is, the more heat it acquires. The best is such as is odoriferous, something strong, full of Spirits, which is neither bitter nor sowr, but pleasant to all the Senses, helping the expulsive Faculty, dissolving ill Humours ; ... 'tis naught for Copulation, because it **dryes** up the Seed, disturbs the Understanding, offends the little skins of the Brain, and hinders Sleep ; whence 'tis to be used for Physick, and not for Drink, unless you use it very moderately, and mixt with much Water : 'Tis naught for young and cholerick persons, but good for old men, especially in Winter.
>
> *Of Rough Wine*
>
> The Wines which are properly Rough, have so small a heat, that they scarce arrive to the first degree, and are **dry** in the second: They are good for the great Heat in quotidian Fevers, Inflammations of the Liver, and dryness of the Stomach; they refresh, take away Thirst, cure Fluxes, stop Vomiting, but let them not be too sharp or sowr, but moderately binding, subtil, and not of too high a colour ; they are good for young men of an hot Stomach, and are naught for flegmatick and old men, because they bind the Breast, beget Coughs, do neither nourish well, nor breed good Blood, and hinder Sweat.
>
> ...
>
> *Of White Wine*
>
> The Wine of a Citron, or Limmon-colour, is called White-wine : It is odoriferous and strong, is hot in the beginning of the second degree, and, **dry** in the first ; it must not be kept longer than a year, for it will be too hot ; ...

In all of these descriptions, the author (or translator) seems to use *dry* in connection with the effects of the particular type of wine on the person who consumes it. That is, because old wine, rough wine, and white wine all have the effect of drying out the drinker's insides, they are aptly characterized as dry in the third, second, or first degree.

---

***Conclusions***

Although *dry* appears as an adjective modifying *wine* in the direct form "dry wine" by 1698 and as a more distant modifier of the form "[Wine] is dry in the third degree" by 1686, it is not at all clear that the use of *dry* in these instances was intended to emphasize a split between dryness and sweetness, rather than between dryness and wateriness or between dryness and flavorfulness.

It seems not at all unlikely that the association of dryness with non-sweetness emerged some time after *dry* (in its wine sense) first caught on in English. The change involved would in any case be far less dramatic than the shift undergone by *racy* from 1726 ("[wine] that has by age lost its luscious quality") to 1751 ("a Wine that still retains its rich Flavour").

Comment: Yes, no one likes wet wine.

Comment: -1: Whilst this a useful historical summary, it doesn't answer the OP's question "what is the origin of the term 'dry' to mean lack of a sweet taste."

Answer (score 4):

The OED claims the earliest record of "dry" as an adjective for "wine" in English is in 1699:

> 8. Of wines, etc.: Free from sweetness and fruity flavour.
>
> 1699   B. E. A New Dictionary of the Terms Ancient and Modern of the Canting Crew
>
> *Dry-wine, a little rough upon, but very grateful to the Palate.*

However, I cannot find the phrase in the online versions of the dictionary.

It is interesting to note that "dry" and the German "trocken" (adj + v.) have the same etymology and the German also uses "trocken" in the same meaning for wine. So it is probably much earlier in origin.

I cannot show it, but this use probably dates back to a now obsolete meaning:

(Also OED)

> †15.a. **Yielding no fruit**, result, or satisfaction; barren, sterile, unfruitful, jejune. (Cf. A. 4) Obsolete (or merged in sense A. 17).
>
> a1340   R. Rolle Psalter vi. 6   *I sall make it to bere froit, þat bifore was drye fra goed werkes.*
>
> 1661   J. Glanvill Vanity of Dogmatizing xviii. 171   *That the fire burns by heat, is an empty dry return to the question, and leaves us still ignorant.*

Moving on and ignoring what the current feeling about sweet and dry wines may be as opposed to what past feeling was, we have:

> **16. Lacking adornment or embellishment, or some addition; meagre, plain, bare; matter-of-fact.**
>
> 1626   W. Laud Wks. (1849) II. 370   *And if they say..they believe them in the Church's sense; yet that dry shift will not serve.*

and

> **17. Deficient in interest; unattractive, distasteful, insipid. (figurative from food that wants succulency.)**
> 1632   R. Burton Anat. Melancholy (ed. 4) i. ii. i. ii. 39   *Our subtile Schoolemen..are weake, drye, obscure.*

It would seem that the figurative use of "dry" is the origin and it is quite old in its association with wine.

Comment: Yes, this (1699) surely predates the 'dry gin' usage. The 'lack of fruit ... fruitiness' argument is persuasive.

Answer (score 2):

The sense of *dry* meaning *lacking sweetness* referring to alcoholic drinks is a few centuries old but its origin is unknown:

***[Dry:](https://www.etymonline.com/word/dry)***

> Of wines, brandy, etc., "free from sweetness or fruity flavor," 1700.

Is may plausibly derive from the sensation you get drinking a dry drink:

From [google.answers](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=709617)

> "Astringency actually is a tactile sensation as opposed to a taste or
> smell. The best way to describe astringency is a dry, puckery
> sensation on the surfaces of the tongue and lining of the mouth.

Comment: The lack of intermediate etymology at Etymon isn't proof that there actually is a total lack of knowledge about this. And one would hope that OP checked here.

Comment: I've always thought that 'dry' was just a translation of 'sec' rather than an independently originated English term. I wonder whether 'sec' carries or carried shades of meaning in French which 'dry' does not in English. After all I'm not sure that the French ever refer to someone having a 'sec' sense of humour.

Comment: French vin sec is as early as 1200 https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/Sec

Comment: That's very relevant information. If you have access, a quote of a few words would really improve your answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It’s from [Jean Bodel’s *Le Jeu de saint Nicolas* of 1200 ᴀᴅ](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Jeu_de_saint_Nicolas), the earliest non-liturgical work written in French that remains to us, whose lines 649–657 run: *Le **vin** aforé de nouvel, / A plain lot et a plain tonnel, / Sade, beavent, et plain et gros, / Rampant comme escuireus en bos, / Sans nul mors de pourri ne d’aigre. / Seur lie court et **sec** et maigre, / Cler con larme de pecheour; / Groupant seur langue a lecheour; / Autre gent n’en doivent gouster.*

Answer (score 2):

I've found *dry* used to describe the taste of some **plums** earlier than its first documented use with *wine*. My opinion is that *siccum, sec, secco, sack*, and (later) their English translation/equivalent *dry* were used to describe something similar to the taste characteristic of unripe fruit (e.g., grapes and plums) and some wine, i.e., *tart* or *unsweet*.

> The red Primordian Plumme is of a reasonable size, long and round,
> reddish on the outside, of a more **dry taste**, and ripe with the
> first sorts in the beginning of August. [John Parkinson; *Paridisi In
> Sole Paradisus Terristrie: A Garden of All Sorts of Pleasant Flowers
> which...*, p.575](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Paridisi_In_Sole_Paradisus_Terristris/vOJBAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=dry%20taste&pg=PA575&printsec=frontcover) (**1629**)

---

> It is from this period that the first use of the word '**dry**' to
> describe a wine that was not sweet appeared, in the doggerel of one
> Richard Ames who published an account of his travels in **1691** round London's taverns in search of 'a bottle of good old **dry** orthodox claret'; he was unable to find it, since all that he was offered was port or madeira.  [Andrew Barr; *Drink*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Drink/vDraAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22It%20is%20from%20this%20period%20that%20the%20first%20use%20of%20the%20word%20%27%20dry%20%27%20to%20describe%20a%20wine%20that%20was%20not%20sweet%20appeared%20,%20in%20the%20doggerel%20of%20one%20Richard%20...%22&dq=%22It%20is%20from%20this%20period%20that%20the%20first%20use%20of%20the%20word%20%27%20dry%20%27%20to%20describe%20a%20wine%20that%20was%20not%20sweet%20appeared%20,%20in%20the%20doggerel%20of%20one%20Richard%20...%22&printsec=frontcover) (1995)

> ...
> So not knowing what Murder and Blood might ensue,
> In hast paid for our
> Drink, and so timely withdrew
> Resolving the dull tedious search to
> give o're,
> And never inquire for **Old Dry Claret** more.
>
> [Richard Ames; "The Last Search After Claret, &C.", allpoetry.com](https://allpoetry.com/The-Last-Search-After-Claret,-&c.) (1691)

Ames uses the same phrase in stanza XV of his ["A Farther Search After Claret..."](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Farther_Search_After_Claret_Or_A_Secon/hKbb2W5vyj4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=ames%20%22old%20dry%20claret%22&pg=PA5&printsec=frontcover) from the same year:

> To the *Ship* then we steer'd with a steddy brisk Gale,
> Where of
> good ***Old dry Claret***  we thought not to fail;

---

> **Sack** (wine), vin d'Espagne, **vin *sec***.—Sherwood, **1650**. Bishop
> Percy cites from an old account-book of the city of Worcester, Anno
> Eliz. 34. Item for a gallon of claret wine, and ***seck***, and a
> pound of sugar." The name was properly given to the **dry** Spanish
> wine such as that still imported under the name of sherry. "*Sherry
> **sack***, so called from Xeres, a sea town of Corduba in Spain, where that kind of sack is made."—Blount, Glossographia in Nares.
> Shakespeare uses sherris and sack as synonyms.
>
> > This valour comes of *sherris*, so that skill in the weapon is nothing
> > without *sack*.—H. IV
>
> Minsheu (1625) explains *sacke*, a wine that cometh out of Spaine,
> Belgicé Roomenije ..., wijn seck, quasi ***siccum***, proper magnam siccandi
> humores facultatem, *giving the right derivation of the word though he
> did not understand the meaning of term **dry** applied to wine*. When
> the proper meaning of the name was so early lost in England, it is not
> surprising that it should have been applied to other strong white
> wines coming from the same quarter, whether sweet or dry,  and we hear
> of Canary and Malaga sacks. Venner ... after discussing medicinally
> the propriety of mixing sugar with sack, adds: "But what I have spoken
> of mixing sugar with sack must be understood of *Sherie sack*, for to
> mix sugar with other wines, that in a common appellation are called
> sack, *and are sweet in taste,* makes it unpleasant to the pallat and
> fulsome to the stomach." "Canarie wine, which beareth the name of the
> islands from whence it is brought, is of some termed a *sacke* with
> this adjunct, sweet." ... [Hensleigh Wedgwood; *Dictionary of English
> Etymology* vol. 3, p.107](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Dictionary_of_English_Etymology/y3IPAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=sack%20dictionary%20etymology&pg=PA107&printsec=frontcover) (1865)

See also [Henderson; *The History of Ancient and Modern Wines*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_History_of_Ancient_and_Modern_Wines/mexdAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=vinum%20siccum&pg=PA298&printsec=frontcover) (1824) for a similar account, as well as a contrasting opinion that *sack* derives from the skin bags in which the Spaniards preserved their wine.

---

Regarding a comment by Stuart F about the use of *sec* in French about 1200, the late date agrees with information about the Italian *secco*:

> *secco* [lat. *siccu(m)* 'secco' di orig. indeur. **1266**] (Zanichelli; *lo Zingarelli* Italian Dictionary)

Answer (score 2):

The term *dry* might have been originated from the wine made from dried or half-dried grapes (raisins) through the term *sack*, a class of wine originally made by fermentation of dried grapes that were dried under the sun. This dried grape wine production method is thought to be originated in ancient times.

Dried grape wines have a bitter taste (if it goes through full fermentation). The drying process of grapes concentrates the sugars through water evaporation. As a result of this, raisins have a higher sugar content than ripe undried grapes. If the grapes are fermented till all the sugar of the grapes is converted to alcohol, it will have high alcohol content and will lack sweetness. An example of dried grape wine from today is the *Amarone* wine from Italy which goes through longer fermentation process. (*Amarone*  means "very bitter" in Italian; which differs from *Recioto* produced in the same region, which is sweeter in taste, because of shorter fermentation process.)

Thus, the term might have been carried through the origins of how the dried grape wine was made from dried grapes to how it tastes as a result of the fermentation process; and applied to all types of wine that lack sweetness (with no residual sugar).

Note: Not all dried grape wines were "dry wines" as some of them had sweet taste based on the fermentation process time and there are levels of dryness as well. Some of the original sack wines had sweet taste also.

Here is an evidence from the book *Inventing Wine: A New History of One of the World's Most Ancient Pleasures* by Paul Lukacs":

> [image] 
> <sub>Source: *[Google Books](https://books.google.ca/books?id=gdIbRb8wXRwC&pg=PT59&lpg=PT59&dq=wine%20dried%20grapes%20sack&source=bl&ots=bq-44ms9Vd&sig=ACfU3U3bfsIla8uJO7_ZvgI5rj64e1m-7A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjI4PrNmY31AhV0jokEHbNlAn0Q6AF6BAgdEAM#v=onepage&q=%22dried%20grapes%22&f=false)*</sub>

Shakespeare has a brief mention of the origin of *sack* in his book *Shakespeare's Twelfth night; or, what you will, with introduction, notes, and plan of preparation*:

> [image] 
> <sub>Source: *[Google Books](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/Shakespeare_s_Twelfth_Night/MosVAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1)*</sub>

Note: I'm checking other sources as well and I might include them.

Answer (score 0):

The adjective 'sweet' is a strange one.  There are few words with as many opposites, depending on the subject matter, particularly in relation to foods but not only so.

- *bitter* (we think of coffee, citrus peel ... beer)
- *sour*  (we think of fruit)
- *salty* (we think of salt!)
- *savoury* (we think of cheese)
- *dry* We think of wine
- *sound* (we think of *harsh*, perhaps, though there are longer words like *cacophonous*)

So central to our being is sweetness, that it becomes a quality in even the abstract and emotional aspects:  love is 'sweet', babies and pet cats are 'sweet', the ideal point of balance or contact is a 'sweet spot' and success is 'sweet' where failure and frustration are 'bitter'.

Perhaps it is not surprising that sweetness applies to so many apparently different things.  It is the first and most desirable and remembered taste/experience in a human life:  the taste of the glucose rich human (or artificial) milk.

Wines are segregated into 'sweet' and 'dry'.  Dictionaries are of little help with this, but there is an official definition of the difference.

> For a wine to be considered dry, it has to have less than 1% of residual sugars.  The driest have little or even no residual sugar.

In other words, the process of fermentation of fruit involves the conversion of the fructose of (say) grapes or apples into alcohol.  The 'sweetness' of wine is then the sugar left over at the end of the fermentation process (over 1%).

The sweet happens to be particularly important not only because of our experiences in our first year or so, but because of the vital role of the sugars in giving us the carbon that can be burned into energy.  So perhaps it is not surprising that we call 'sweet' many unrelated things that are pleasant or make us happy.

What all this shows is that 'sweet' is an extraordinarily important and diverse word in our vocabulary and is so in all the languages of which I am aware:  *doux*, *dolce*, glykos (γλύκος), dulcis, all have a similar breadth of use.  The Roman Catullus writes of his girlfriend, 'Lesbia', "...dulce ridentem" (*sweetly laughing*), and Sappho describes love as a "glukupikron orpeton" (*sweetbitter creature*) sneaking up on her and troubling her.

Despite all this, the paradox remains that something liquid is being described as the opposite of wet:  *dry*

I can find no exact explanation for this.  The origin of the word *dry* itself in Etymonline does offer a shadow of a clue, however.

It comes from the Middle English *drie*, meaning, of course, *without water*, that other element vital to life.  But gin is a liquid.

There is, however, a usage of the 12th century shows a wider use, of *barren*, a natural extension of dry, in the sense of the inability to ground to be productive in the absence of sufficient water (Etymonline).  It gradually extends to application to alcaholic beverages  by 1700.

> Meaning "barren" is mid-14c. Of persons, "showing no emotion," c. 1200; of humor or jests, "without show of pleasantry, caustic, sarcastic" early 15c. (implied in dryly). Sense of "uninteresting, tedious" is from 1620s. Of wines, brandy, etc., "free from sweetness or fruity flavor," 1700.

Comment: Very interesting...  but, as it stands, not an answer to the OP!

Answer (score -2):

According to a post by [pinkfreud-ga in Google Answers](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=709617) in 2006 the earliest attested use of dry to mean dry wine comes from a work in French by Jean Bodin called *Le Jeu de St Nicolas* around 1200. He used the term *vin* (wine) *sec*.

The poster states that there is no authoritative source that describes why that word was chosen to describe wine that isn't sweet and states that the most likely explanation is to do with 'mouth-feel' in that such wine tends to dry out the mouth.

Another possibility occurs to me when one explores the etymology of dry:

> of persons "showing no emotion" c.1200, ... "without show of pleasantry, caustic, sarcastic", early 15C.

Now sweetness is often used to describe pleasantness. So lack of sweetness is lack of pleasantness. Lack of pleasantness is dryness. Hence dry wine meaning wine without sweetness.

Comment: Might actually be more interesting to seek out and add a link to the original French citation rather than citing someone on some outdated website who commented something rather interesting.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: I've referred to it already in my post. The post was not out of date and was pretty detailed. And I doubt very much whether Jean Bodin's play will explain why the term dry was chosen to describe wine that is not sweet. If you feel otherwise, feel free to check it out yourself rather than suggesting other people do your own work for you.

Comment: The post cited is from 2006. The link I added was from the source: Google Answers, which was not easy to find right away. I did the "work" to help future users/visitors. It's called courtesy. Not my downvote.

Comment: Luckily someone also cited the same source, here's the [link to the answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/581957/44619) posted several hours before yours. It contains the link to the website and in the comments, tchrist posted [the French citation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/581955/what-is-origin-of-the-term-dry-to-mean-lack-of-a-sweet-taste/582072#comment1453560_581957), which I thought rather helpful.